# HTTP Response Error Handling Angular Application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a data.json file as below.

```
[
    {"value":1},
    {"value":2},
    {"value":3},
    {"value":3}
]
```

& I am using Http to get the data. Data is coming properly but what if my server is turned off, then it throws error i want to show some custom message to user instead of that error. Below is my function which fetches the data.

```
 data: any;

  getData() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost/php/data.json').subscribe((res) => {
      this.data = res;
      console.log(this.data);
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }
```

Comment: [Read the docs!](https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  getData() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost/php/data.json').subscribe((res) => {
      this.data = res;
      console.log(this.data);
    },(err:HttpErrorResponse)=>{handle your error here});
```

subscribe accepts error handling callback as 2nd argument. You can check API details here

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse

Comment: Cannot find name 'HttpErrorResponse' this error is coming

Comment: It's correct, but I recommend user `.catch( ( err: Error) => { handleErrors; } ) ` 'cause you can handle errors of code into response function

Comment: use import {HttpErrorResponse } from @angular/common/http

Comment: this works well but if the data is not coming http takes around 10 seconds & then throws error. I dont want the user to wait for 10 seconds

Comment: Then you use `timeout` operator. It has nothing to do with error handling.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the catchError opertor provided by the rxjs

```
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators'

this.http.get('http://localhost/php/data.json')
    .pipe ( 
       catchError((error) => // handle the error here; )
     )
    .subscribe((res) => {
      this.data = res;
      console.log(this.data);
    })
```

Comment: keep in mind that you have to emit value from `catchError` which will be passed down to the subscriber

Answer (score 3):

if you want to capture a specific instance than :

```
getData() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost/php/data.json').subscribe((res) => {
      this.data = res;
      console.log(this.data);
    }, (err:HttpErrorResponse) => {
        consdole.log(err)
     })
  }
```

> I will suggest you to use  `intercepter` for centralise the `error`
>   handling:

http-intercepter.ts:

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpEvent,
    HttpHeaders,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpResponse,
    HttpErrorResponse,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpRequest
} from '@angular/common/http';



import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private appService: AppService) {

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param req - parameter to handle http request
     * @param next - parameter for http handler
     */
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const started = Date.now();
        /**
         * Handle newly created request with updated header (if given)
         */
        return next.handle(req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            /**
             * Sucessfull Http Response Time.
             */
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                const elapsed = Date.now() - started;
            }

        }, (err: any) => {
            /**
             * redirect to the error_handler route according to error status or error_code
             * or show a modal
             */
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

in module.ts:

providers: [

```
{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: TokenInterceptor,
    multi: true,
}
]
```